# Помогите с адаптером для recyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть кастомный `recyclerView` у которого есть адаптер. Вот его код:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.SenderHolder> {

    private Integer type;
    private List<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;
    private static final String keyOutboundMessageId = "outbound_message_id";
    private static final String keyIncomingMessageId = "incoming_message_id";
    private static final String keyDraftMessageId = "draft_message_id";

    ListAdapter(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx, int type) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.type = type;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SenderHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);

        return new SenderHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SenderHolder holder, int position) {
        final Message message = messageList.get(position);

        holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        boolean attachment = message.isAttachment();
        Integer new_one = message.getNewField();

        if (attachment) {
            holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getSender_name());
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
                break;
        }

        if (new_one == 1 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(message.getSender_name())) {
            holder.tvSubject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.tvDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.tvFrom.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }

        holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());


        DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
        String isoString = message.getDate();
        try {
            Date date = isoFormat.parse(isoString);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
            holder.tvDate.setText(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                switch (type) {
                    case 0:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyOutboundMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyIncomingMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyDraftMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                }

                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }

    class SenderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;
        final ImageView attachIV;
        final CheckBox checkBox;

        SenderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
            tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            attachIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clip);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_item);
        }
    }
}
```

он используется для формирования списка сообщений (входящих, исходящих, черновиков). Хочу сделать функцию выделения нескольких элементов списка. Как можно увидеть из адаптера, при длительном нажатии у меня пропадает дата поступления письма и индикатор наличия вложенных файлов. Все вроде так как я хочу, но почему-то после длительного нажатия на сообщение, после пропадания даты и индикатора, я все-равно открываю сообщение. А мне нужно, чтобы после длительного нажатия у  меня у всех сообщений пропадали дата и индикатор прикрепленных файлов, и появлялись checkbox для выделения, без открытия сообщения. Пока не стоит вопрос о получении id выделенных сообщений, просто нужно как-то сделать такое поведение.

### UPDATE

для того чтобы не было перехода на другое активити нужно было просто поменять значение булевской переменной в функции длительного нажатия. Теперь она выглядит так:

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

теперь осталось только сделать так чтобы на всех элементах списка пропадали дата и индикатор вложенного файла, при длительном нажатии на один элемент.

Заранее спасибо за помощь и ценные советы по решению данной проблемы.

Comment: вводите в адаптер поле, назовем его editMode, значения true/false,  в LongClickListener ставите этому полю true и обновляете адаптер через notifyAllChange. По завершении режима ставите полю false и опять обновляете. в onBindViewHolder делаете ветвление, по типу как у вас  с attacment, но по состоянию editMode (что показывать что скрывать в каждом из режимов). в onLongClick никакой логики работы с виджетами не надо, только логика изменения переменой

Comment: @pavlofff, я вот все сижу и пытаюсь сделать то что вы сказали, но почему-то не получается, не очень понятно две вещи - обновление адаптера через notifyAllChange и не очень понятно как использовать слушатель изменения состояния чекбокса в паре с функцией обновления адаптера, если не сложно то объясните немного поподробнее :)

Comment: метод обновления данных адаптера notifyDataSetChanged() а не notifyAllChange

Comment: это его нужно в адаптере писать? я просто думал что в адаптере все будет так же как и в активити, с функцией `recreate()` но походу нет

Comment: метод обновляет айтемы адаптера - внесли изменения-обновили виджеты

Comment: его нужно override сделать? или самому сделать? просто я то вроде видел где-то такой метод, но его нельзя вызвать в моем адаптере

Comment: обычный метод обновления данных, часть класса recyclerview.adapter. ничего не надо переопрделять или самому делать. доступен для всех наследников адаптера recyclerview и конечно описан в документации

Comment: я то постепенно начинаю понимать что вы имеете в виду, но не до конца, если я правильно понял, после того как я где-то пропишу вызов этого метода у меня будет после появления у одного элемента списка checkbox у всех остальных элементов тоже он будет появляться, просто нужно в каком-то нужном месте его прописать и все?