# Как обновить адаптер для кастомного recyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть подобный вопрос по этой теме - [Помогите с адаптером для recyclerView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889297/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-recyclerview) где мне посоветовали использовать функцию notifyDataSetChanged(). Я прочитал про этот метод, и понял что человек который мне посоветовал это был прав. Но проблему я не решил. Пробовал запихнуть это все в функцию и вызывать из конструктора, но получается почти то что нужно, кроме того что когда я делаю длительно нажатие у меня у предыдущего элемента списка все пропадает то что мне нужно, а у остальных элементов все остается по-прежнему. Вот что мне нужно убрать и добавить:

```
holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

но проблема в том что это у меня в холдере используется и далеко от холдера я не могу уйти. Сделал бул переменную - `private boolean editMode` которая ставится `true` когда я делаю длительное нажатие на элемент. Но вопрос в том где мне проверку вставить так, чтобы эта переменная постоянно проверялась. То что эту проверку нужно писать не в конструкторе я уже понял, но тогда я не могу понять где ее писать. Надеюсь что решение лежит на поверхности, и моя проблема решаемая.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте сеттер для этого свойства по типу:

```
public void setEditMode(boolean enable) {
    if (this.editMode != enable) {
        this.editMode = enable;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

И вызывайте его когда надо включить/выключить режим редактирования.
Или можно сделать метод по типу "переключатель":

```
public void toogleEditMode() {
    this.editMode = !this.editMode;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

P.S. В `onBindViewHolder` должно быть условие, выбирающее видимость в зависимости от режима:

```
if (editMode) {
    holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

А в лонг-клике только вызов метода смены режима

Comment: я сделал такой сеттер как вы создали, дальше я его вызываю когда у меня происходит длительное нажатие на элемент списка, но у меня почему-то меняется только верхний элемент, а остальные не меняются, а изменения у верхнего заключаются в том что у него только пропадают элементы а чекбокс не появляется, вероятнее всего я использую эту функцию не там где нужно, или не так как нужно.

Comment: по логике должно все скрываться, когда у меня выполняется условие, но attachIV не скрывается хотя все прописано

Comment: Проверьте инициализацию холдера, `id`, разметку - на тот ли вью ссылается эта переменная?

Comment: просто так получается, что когда у меня пропадало все только у одного элемента, то пропадали все элементы, а теперь когда мы пытаемся все сделать для всех элементов списка, то почему-то так не получается